# HTACCESS : how to simplify my RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a photo section of my website and when choosing which picture to view you have different navigation menu to get what you want (Latest, Trending, Friends, Favorite etc. ) there is also the possibility to sort the pictures by Date, Rating, views etc.

Ohh and there is also a system of pagination that I'm using to only display a few pictures a page.

For now I have this :

```
RewriteRule ^photo$ photo.php?tab=latest
RewriteRule ^photo/trending$ photo.php?tab=trending
RewriteRule ^photo/friends$ photo.php?tab=friends
RewriteRule ^photo/favorite$ photo.php?tab=favorite

RewriteRule ^photo/page:([0-9]+)/$ photo.php?tab=latest&page=$1
RewriteRule ^photo/trending/page:([0-9]+)/$ photo.php?tab=trending&page=$1
RewriteRule ^photo/friends/page:([0-9]+)/$ photo.php?tab=friends&page=$1
RewriteRule ^photo/favorite/page:([0-9]+)/$ photo.php?tab=favorite&page=$1

RewriteRule ^photo/sort:([A-Za-z0-9]+)/page:([0-9]+)/$ photo.php?tab=latest&page=$2&sort=$1
RewriteRule ^photo/trending/sort:([A-Za-z0-9]+)/page:([0-9]+)/$ photo.php?tab=trending&page=$2&sort=$1

And so on
```

I am wondering it there is some kind of possibility to have the .htaccess file detect any `page:([0-9]+)` and with that automatically send a variable with the page number to the php file. This would be quite helpful because I also have a article, video and forum section which will have the same kind of features.

Comment: I think the better solution would be to use a front controller pattern, redirecting all photo/ URLs to photo.php, and have photo.php use some sort of router ([Shameless plug](http://brandonwamboldt.ca/my-php-router-class-825/)). It would be cleaner, more maintainable and more extensible.

Comment: okay thanks, I'm going to look into that.

Comment: So I'm trying the php class router you linked, but I'm not finding how to use it. There isn't a lot of documentation on how to use it. Could you show me an example of how I could use for my case ? And also do you think it would be a good idea to replace all my .htaccess RewriteRule by this class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing with this:

```
# Extract out the "page" and "sort" parts of the URI, and append them to the query string
RewriteRule (.*)/page:([0-9]+)/(.*) /$1/$3?page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)/sort:([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.*) /$1/$3?sort=$2 [L,QSA]

# Proceed with the regular routing
RewriteRule ^photo/?$ photo.php?tab=latest  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^photo/trending/?$ photo.php?tab=trending [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^photo/friends/?$ photo.php?tab=friends [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^photo/favorite/?$ photo.php?tab=favorite [L,QSA]
```

The key here is to use the `QSA` flag everywhere, so as the query string gets put together, new bits can be appended as needed. The other thing is the regular routing part, I added `/?` to the end of the regular expression match because gue to the page/sort processing, you could end up with trailing slashes.